# dataframe index groupby error ValueError: 'GL' is both an index level and a column label

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have this code which runs well until this morning:

```
# delete rows of 2019
        df.drop(df[df.month.str.contains('2019')].index, inplace=True)

        df.sort_values(by=['GL',  'month'], inplace=True)
        df["diffDebit"] = df.groupby('GL')['GL_Debit'].diff().fillna(df['GL_Debit'])
        df["diffCredit"] = df.groupby('GL')['GL_Credit'].diff().fillna(df['GL_Credit'])
```

error is :
ValueError: 'GL' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

If I delete 
df.drop(df[df.month.str.contains('2019')].index, inplace=True)

It works again, but I need to delete these rows before. Any idea?

Template of dataframe:
[image]

Comment: Please show a print of your DataFrame.

Comment: Be explicit. Try:  df["diffDebit"] = df.groupby('GL').loc[:, 'GL_Debit'].diff().fillna(df.loc[:, 'GL_Debit'])

Comment: I tried you solution but it des not work Error :Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: find sample of dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution:

in fact just add `[]` for `['GL']` in groupby as follows:

```py
df["diffDebit"] = df.groupby(['GL'])['GL_Debit'].diff().fillna(df['GL_Debit'])
```